# Is there #Region code for HTML

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, region

In VB and C# there are `#Region ... #endRegion` and have it collapsable. Is there a similar way to do this in HTML?

Right now I just have comments blocking where the different elements are on my HTML page, but I would like to have a single collapse point instead of all of the `<tr>` `<td>` and `<div>` tags collapsed.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This indeed depends on the IDE, just noticed today that the newest version of the free Web Essentials 2012 plugin for Visual Studio has added region support in HTML.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6

http://vswebessentials.com/changelog

```
  <!--#region main  -->


  <!--#endregion -->
```

Comment: This still works in Visual Studio 2013, Web Essentials is still required.

Comment: `<!-- region Region Name -->` and `<!-- endregion -->`  works in Intellij

Answer (score 17):

As of Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 regions are now supported in the HTML editor. You may use the built in code snippet: type "

```
<!-- #region SampleRegion -->
<!-- #endregion -->
```

You can find the details of this improvement and other new features in [update 4 here.](http://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2013-update4-rc-vs#AzureWeb)

Answer (score 12):

I think the short answer is no.

Region is only a IDE directive recognised by the editor (Visual Studio).  There is nothing in the HTML standard and anything you did put in the HTML would be sent straight down to the browser too, so I've not come across anything and can't imagine there would ever be anything.

Answer (score 10):

Highlight the section you want collapsed, then go to `Edit -> Outlining -> Hide Selection`

Reference: [How to: Collapse and Expand HTML Elements in Visual Web Developer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178155.aspx)

**Edit:** This assumes you're using Visual Studio

Comment: As per @Jim's original statement in his question, this only allows existing HTML sections to be collapsed, you can't wrap several HTML elements in a #region and collapse that - closest you could do is a DIV element, but then that would be sent down to the client too.

Comment: I don't believe it does. I just collapsed the middle of a paragraph using this method.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  It's an extra bit of functionality I've not come across before.  It nearly does the same as a region but you can't appear to give it a name and if you hide 3 lines, the "..." showing the hidden selection appears as the start of the 4th line (rather than a line of it's own) but it is hidden the section.  And like you say, it is completely IDE driven and could work inside an HTML element or encompass part of 2 or more distinct elements.

Comment: Yeah, it does lack the naming functionality. So, it's a partial solution.

Answer (score 4):

For Html:

```
<!--#region -->
        Code code code...
<!--#endregion -->
```

For Javascript:

```
// #region
        Code code code...
// #endregion
```

As you see, Visual Studio states region blocks inside of comments.

`<!-- -->` sign of comment in Html

`//`  sign of comment in Javascript

Answer (score 4):

In order for outlining to work in visual studio 2019, make sure to have space before and after the comment closing tags:

```
<!-- #region -->
    <!--Blazor Components Signal-R server-->
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script src="~/lib/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!--Bootstrap bundle-->
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- #endregion -->
```

[image]

**Note**: this won't work in `Visual Studio 2022` yet.

Answer (score 3):

I used div tag to collapse html code blocks :

```
<div>
  Code Blocks...
</div>
```

before I learn

```
<!--#region explanation blocks  -->
        Code Blocks...
<!--#endregion -->
```

both of them solve problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for your collapse  comments

```
<!-- Your comment caption -->
   <div class="hidden">
       Put Your comments here
   </div>
```

So div can collapse or expand in html code in VS

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```html
<% # region %>

<% # endregion %>
```

Comment: I fixed your image link, but given you don't mention anything about what IDE it is, and the code snippet you present, when run, does nothing, this is unlikely to be of very much use to anyone...

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, sometimes the region feature works for me in Visual Studio 2022, and sometimes it does not. I tried many of the above, and it is hit or miss as to whether the region is actually created or not.

But I have found this to work every time:

```
 <div data-region="My Header Region">This is my Header Region</div>
 </div>
```

It collapses every time, and it shows the region name plainly.

**Updated thanks to @AndrewMorton comment.

Comment: It seems to be a bad idea to create another level of `<div>` just for the UI in the development environment.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, see update.

Comment: That looks like an improvement!

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code, this can be done by using the correct syntax:

```
<!-- #region -->
...
Code
...
<!-- #endregion -->
```

Make sure there are no spaces between the `#` and `region` or `endregion`.